# Google Tag Manager problem with multiple containers on a page

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am trying to add another container in GTM for landing page.

Main site: https://aaa.com/
(**ContainerA** is working.)

Landing Page site: https://aaa.com/lp/
(**ContainerB** which I want to add.)

(1) At first, I add **ContainerB** with 5 tags.

(2) And then, I added the following custom Javascript code (variable) in **ContainerA**.

```
function () {
  var paths = location.pathname.split('/');
  if (paths.length >= 2) return paths[1];
  return "none";
}
```

(3) Next, I added the following Lookup Table (variable) in **ContainerA**.

```
Input: lp
Output: GTM-(**ContainerB**) <-- **ContainerB** ID
```

(4) And finally, I published the **ContainerA**.

Also, I updated the following code to the landing page.

**head section**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ContainerA ID');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ContainerB ID');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

**body section**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-ContainerA ID"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-ContainerB ID"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

What I want to do is to preview **ContainerB** but it isn't working. Open ContainerB and click Preview button, Tag Assistant is opened. Then I enter the URL (https://aaa.com/lp/), another window is launched and open the LP page.

But I can't see **ContainerB ID** and any tags in **ContainerB**. It only shows **ContainerA ID** and tags in **ContainerA**. So I can't know tags in **ContainerB** will work.

How can I see preview of **ContainerB**?
Would you help me in this issue to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

After all, I only need to add tags to head section and body section.

**head section**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js? 
id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ContainerA ID');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js? 
id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ContainerB ID');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

**body section**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-ContainerA ID"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe> 
</noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-ContainerB ID"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```